# How to use colored patterns inside transparent image

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I’m trying to create a game (Middle Age concept), but i’m stuck in forming the shields. I want every colony to have his own unique shield, which will be consisted by:

1. Shield shape (14 shapes)
2. Pattern (12 patterns)
3. Color (16 x 2 colors, since every pattern will have 2 color choices)
4. Symbol (12 symbols)

I’ve already created the shield shapes using photoshop. Every shield shape will have its border and it will be transparent inside and outside. 
My goal is every user to be able to choose the pattern, the 2 colors and the symbol of his shield, which will represent his faction.

There is one way to create all these different combinations and put them by using css and jquery, but this option will demand a huge number of colored patterns:

14 shapes x 12 patterns x 16x2 colors = 5.376 (different colored patterns at least).

So my questions are:

1. How can i show the picture correctly when someone click's on the shield icons? In order to change the main shield by clicking on one of the smaller shapes underneath, i used the following jquery code, but for some unexplained reason it doesn’t work on fiddle, while it properly works on my local server.

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       $("#shield-1").click(function() {
           $('.modal-shield img').attr('src',function(i,e){
               $(this).attr('src', "path/to-image/shield-1.png");
           });
       });
   });
   ```
2. How can i present inside the shield its own pattern, according to each different shape? Can i use the option "overflow" on css, in order to fill his interior transparent part and then with jquery to create the patterns?
3. How can i change the color of the pattern?
4. Is there a way to save as an image the result of all those options, in order to later show the shield on different sizes?

If it’s possible, i would like to use css and Jquery, but if this option isn’t possible can i use svg and Jquery?

PS. I created a fiddle, but since i don’t know how to include it here i will add it to my next comment.

Comment: That's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/snart1/4ef46nro/3/

Comment: Your question is too broad, and is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Attempt a solution and we are here to help if you strike problems.

Comment: Fair enough... 
I will try some solutions i found and i 'll come back, if any problems occur.

Anyway, i'm open to listen to any suggestions or advises you believe will help me accomplice that project..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem about question #1, i used the following updated jquery code to change main shield by clicking on shapes underneath

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("[id^='shield-']").click(function() {     
        var mysrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $('.modal-shield img').attr('src',function(i,e){            
            $(this).attr('src', mysrc);
        });
    });
});
```

When any id starts with "shield_" clicked, variable "mysrc" get's his src attribute, and then changes class "modal-shield" img with "myscr" value..
Hope it help's someone...